# Changing Pledge amount on the stake pool

Tags: stake-pool, pledge

I would like to increase the pledged amount on my stake pool. I searched online and I learned that I need to generate a new pool.cert among other things and that the change will take effect in two epochs. My question is: If I generate and re-register my pool with the new pool  certificate and my pool is assigned to mint block with-in those two epochs, will it mint those blocks or do I lose them since they were assigned/associated to the old certificate?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a new pool registration certificate, you will change some of the parameters, like pledge in your case. It has no influence on the blocks the pool is minting. The only potential problem is that you wont't match the new pledge, if you increase it and there is not enough ADA in your wallet after 2 full epochs, but the blocks will still be minted and adopted, you just won't win rewards for them. Another potential problem is changing the VRF or COLD keys by mistake when submitting a new pool registration certificate. This should not happen.

Answer (score 0):

> If I generate and re-register my pool with the new pool certificate and my pool is assigned to mint block with-in those two epochs, will it mint those blocks or do I lose them since they were assigned/associated to the old certificate?

Correct. The new certificate you submit is not valid until 2 epochs after you submit it.